# Whats up with eval()?

Tags: javascript, eval

I've seen a lot about how the `eval()` function is evil; not a wise choice for HTML/JavaScript programming. I would like to use a function where I can pass in a string to have it read as a variable name, and `eval()` seems to do just that, but I don't want to use a destructive function.

From what I understand, the issue with `eval()` is that it can read third-party input as actual code, which opens a door for malicious activity. I have a map element that keeps track of location using strings for the location names. I also have large blocks of text assigned to variables so I can pull up a description of the current location easily. This seems like an acceptable time to use `eval`, as the strings that I would be passing in would be provided by other parts of the code. Is this a fair judgement, or is there some other function that I should be using?

Comment: An easy way to get around that is to save whatever variable you're interested in accessing in a javascript Object (i.e. key-value pairs), and access them via indexing. This simple use case doesn't need `eval`.

Comment: I guess my issue with that was that the key I would be using to access the variable is already being used as a key for other values. I guess I could put the variable at index 0 so that it could be easily found, but I am worried that it might complicate my ability to find the other values in the object. Does that make any sense?

Comment: What about creating separate objects for the separate use cases?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean

Comment: Didn't you get this answered in [your question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71317003/283366)?

Comment: Not exactly. That one was for tracking location, but I needed to display a message depending on location. I figured using eval() to read the contents of the variable rather than the name would work just fine, but though it might be better to check in case I was advised against it, and I was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Moving my comment as an answer)

An easy way to get around that is to save whatever variable you're interested in accessing in a javascript Object (i.e. key-value pairs), and access them via indexing. This simple use case doesn't need `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

> From what I understand, the issue with eval() is that it can read third-party input as actual code, which opens a door for malicious activity.

This is not the only reason. One could argue that by today's standards the performance of JavaScript code is negligible.

However, one has to take into account that `eval()` actually invokes the JavaScript interpreter which is significantly slower than writing the code upfront. [¹](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

> I would like to use a function where I can pass in a string to have it read as a variable name, and eval() seems to do just that, but I don't want to use a destructive function.

This does not warrant the use of `eval()`. As mentioned in the comments, you can achieve this with keeping track of variables in an object:

```
let vars = {}

vars["some_variable_name"] = "test"

const var_name = "some_variable_name"

console.log(vars[var_name]) // "test"
```

> as the strings that I would be passing in would be provided by other parts of the code

Might be, but what if in the future some piece of that code actually does process *some* user input?

Not worth the performance penality and obvious security risk in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

For a simple way to use a variable name as a string is to use an Object (called a dictionary or map in some languages)

```js
const stringToGrade = {
  "freshman": 9,
  "sophomore": 10,
  "junior": 11,
  "senior": 12,
};

document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click",  () => {
  const asString = document.querySelector("#inp").value.toLowerCase();
  const grade = stringToGrade[asString];
  console.log(`Your grade number is ${grade}`);
});
```

```html
<input id="inp" placeholder="Enter your grade level (freshman, sophomore, etc.)" />
<button id="btn">Submit</button>
```